# Perl intermittently fails to connect to iis 7.5 (cygwin on windows server 2012)

Tags: perl, ssl, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012-r2

We upgraded perl on our windows server 2012 to latest stable version. Ever since we did that we are getting intermittent Cannot connect to the server errors throwing 500 error responses.

But it is so intermittent we cannot identify the problem. Here is the debug log for some idea:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:763: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:773: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:783: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:803: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:759: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:763: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:766: local error: SSL connect attempt failed
```

Windows server is running IIS 7.5 and We have a valid Certificate issued by COMODO.

Any insight would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: There should be more debug output after that, especially a "fatal SSL error:..." which contains more details about the error. Apart from that - which version of IO::Socket::SSL, Net::SSLeay and openssl is in use?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I could not find any other error logs other than these. But updating windows fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So updating windows server 2012 (my OS), which has not been updated in over a year fixed the problem. There must have been some windows patch for new tls support.